# Need help on finding values in one table and do not in exists in the other table and vice versa

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm using Oracle.

I have 2 tables, each table has a userID and entitlementID. I want to select the entitlements that exist in table 1 but not in table 2 and vice versa. I need the output to look like:

```
USER_ID| ENTITLEMENT_1 | ENTITLEMENT_2

 33    |    44    |    <NULL>
 54    |    <NULL>|    55
 33    |    <NULL>|    32
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not just a simple outer join if you are looking *only* for those entitlements that exist in one table and not the other.

```
SELECT t1.userid, t1.entitlement_1, NULL AS entitlement_2
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 
                     WHERE t2.userid = t1.userid
                       AND t2.entitlement_2 = t1.entitlement_1 )
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.userid, NULL AS entitlement_1, entitlement_2
  FROM table2 t2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
                     WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid
                       AND t1.entitlement_1 = t1.entitlement_2 )
```

The first select finds the userid and entitlement_1 pairs that don't exist in table2, and the second select does the opposite. You didn't give a lot of information about the tables involved, like if userid or (userid, entitlement) is a primary key or anything, so this might be able to be optimized.

Comment: no, neither table will have a primary key; in truth this is part of a bigger query I am doing.

One more question though; the entitlements in table1 are of the form "*/*/fis/<the entitlement id>" do you know how i would filter so i jut get the entitlement id comparing to the table2 entitlement id

Comment: You would have to extract the id, probably using either `SUBSTR` or `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, as in `SUBSTR(t1.entitlement_1, 9) = t2.entitlement_2` (or something to that effect). Be aware that using a function like that will bypass indexes if you have any on the t1.entitlement column and can slow down your query.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a full outer join to accomplish this task.

Here is more info on outer joins:

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins)

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT userID FROM Table2)
  AS t2 ON t1.userID=t2.userID
```

Comment: How would that retrieve entitlement_2 from table2?

Comment: when you using SELECT * and JOIN the results contains all columns from all tables referenced in an ON clause

Comment: Oh geez, I totally didn't even notice the *